# Most Accurate way to determine Location

Tags: location

Just one simple question, Is there any way more accurate than GPS to determine user's location (Latitude and Longitude)? I don't mean only for mobile phone users, I mean generally!

Comment: If it is meant generally, then it is probably off-topic here. And I kinda miss the coding question here.

Comment: More accurate than GPS? You need precision better than a few meters?

Comment: [GPS with RKP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Precise_monitoring) can do about 10cm (4") accuracy. Do you need better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, no.  There's no inherent relationship between an IP address and a global location.  Though that would be pretty cool.  Ex-girlfriends everywhere, rejoice!

Websites that infer my location have very few sources of data.  The location where my IP is registered (which might be found with whois, etc.,) is the most common.  Sitting in my office, that address in a very close approximation to where I am, but it's not like my office publishes a list of IP addresses and their lat/long coordinates.

When I'm at home, my IP address is distributed by my internet service provider and while they probably know everything there is to know about me, they keep careful wraps on that information.  They're not likely to provide an API that lets you get at info about where my particular IP address is serviced.

Google has a bit more info to work with, particularly if you're an avid user of google maps.  They can assume that when I'm logged in as the same person from the same IP address and request directions to or from a particular address on a regular basis.... that's probably where I am.  You will be unlikely to have that sort of data at your fingertips.

If you really need a hyper-accurate measurement of your location, you're probably stuck hiring a surveyor.  I wouldn't recommend it.  It was as expensive as hell when I had to get one, but it was cool watching him bounce lasers through my hall to the backyard to get enough reference points.  =]